# How to add glyphicons in haml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, glyphicons

**I have this .haml file where I want to add glyphincon instead of showing text like I have shown below in the link_to. I have tried to look it up online and it is not working. Can someone help me out? I want the 'Show' and 'Edit' in link_to replaced by glyphicons.**

%td= link_to 'Show', order

%td= link_to 'Edit', edit_order_path(order)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the HTML tag required for the icon you need, like so:

```
%td= link_to '<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-glass"></span>'.html_safe, order
```

The `.html_safe` method is necessary to avoid escaping the HTML code.